# How can I replace the text between two delimiters with a blank?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have a message, received via an input field. For example:

```
This is *red* colour.
```

I want to replace everything between the two asterisks with a blank line ("___") so the outcome would be:

```
This is ___ colour.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A one-liner would be `message.replace(/\*.*?\*/g, '___');`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "This is *red* color";
  var startIndex = nthIndex(str,'*',1);
  var endIndex = nthIndex(str,'*',2);
  var output = str.replace(str.substring(startIndex, (endIndex+1)), "_");
}

function nthIndex(str, pat, n){
    var L= str.length, i= -1;
    while(n-- && i++<L){
        i= str.indexOf(pat, i);
        if (i < 0) break;
    }
    return i;
}
```